# Unmet dependencies when installing expect and libiw-dev

Tags: update

Every time I run the command sudo apt-get upgrade this is what I get. What should I do?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 expect : Depends: tcl8.5 (>= 8.5.0) but it is not installed
 libiw-dev : Depends: libiw30 (= 30~pre9-8) but 30~pre9-12 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running `apt --fix-broken install` produces:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the error message you should try to run `apt --fix-broken install` or preferably using `sudo` as the error message to that hints "are you root?".

So go with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```